# Get square out of rectangle without deformation in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have a small application with `Map` and I want to make something like the minimap.

**Illustration of the problem:**
[image]

**White area** (rectangle, not square, it's **1200x800px**) represents `Map` and **green area** represents crop (square with radius (about **800x800px**)), which I want to get from map.

Whenever I tried to do it, (I tried using `ShaderEffectSource` and `OpacityMask`), whole the `Map` was taken and resized to square, so output was deformed.

I want to take only that part of `Map`, that is covered by the green area.

```
Rectangle {
    id: map
    width: 1200
    height: 800
    color: "white"
    Rectangle {
        id: mask
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 800
        height: 800
        radius: width/2
    }
}
```

How can I achieve something like that?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: This is my current code

```
ShaderEffectSource {
    visible: true
    id: shaderEffect
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: parent.height
    height: parent.height
    sourceItem: map
    layer.enabled: true
    layer.effect: OpacityMask {
        maskSource: Rectangle {
            width: map.height
            height: map.height
            radius: width/2
        }
    }
}
```

//EDIT: Added image

**My deformed result**
[image: Map]
As you can see map is deformed - original size of Map component is resized from 1200x800 to 800x800 (Circle size). My goal is to crop everything that is outside of circle.

Comment: Do you want to get a green circle? if so, you just have to set a radius: `Rectangle {
            id: mask
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            width: 800
            height: 800
            radius: 400
            color: "green"
        }`

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to do. Cut circle from the map? Mask the area outside the circle? You have to clarify the question.

Comment: I want to cut circle from map (wich Is 1200x800). Circle should be center of map (800x800). My output Is circle cut out of that map, but it's width of map (1200) shrinked to width of that circle (800), thus it's deformated. I want to cut circle out of that map, but I want to crop everything that Is outside of that circle and show only that part of map, that Is under circle.

Comment: Maybe try `maskSource: mask`

Comment: @augre I tried, result is what you see on last picture (deformed)